# On Android app close and reopen call a function

Tags: android

I need to call a function on app start, on app puse and on app resume. 
I know we can do this from an activity context but how to do this from the app context. Refer the following code and can you please suggest me where I should place the call to stopShakeDetect() and startShakeDetect().

```
public class MyApp extends Application implements ShakeDetector.Listener {


    public void stopShakeDetect() {
        /*
            start shake detection
        */
    }

    public void startShakeDetect() {
        /*
            Stop shake detection
        */
    }



}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you give us a vague textual explanation of your code. nobody will be willing to try to understand how your code looks like and then try to fix it for you in his head. short: show us (minimal) code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well when your app first starts it's almost always going to start on the main activity that you determined. So call the function in the onStart in that function. Then for onPause and onResume just put your code in all of your activities since you never know which activity the user will want to pause or resume from.

Comment: Sure thats a way to go. But I just wanted to know whether we have something like onPause and onResume for the app context rather than the activity. Sorry if my question sounds odd I'm just starting with android.

Comment: No thats fine I just started with Android a couple months ago as well, but as far as I know there is no way to interact with the app as a whole. I am a newbie as well so don't take my word for it.